# Causes for sudden increase in reads

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've seen a sudden increase in reads on my Google Cloud SQL instance. Is there anything that could have caused this? As far as I'm aware nothing has changed in the database or application.

It's jumped from an average of 5 per second to over 100. The instance is located in the EU region

Comment: Either you now have 20 times more users, or someone is having fun with your application.

Comment: There was no notable increase in the number of queries or questions. Just an increase in the number of reads

Comment: I understand troubleshooting this may be hard.... but we need more information, something, ANYTHING so we can provide some help here....